# Convert wordpress post/page title & tags to meta keywords without plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, keyword

This was easier for me when I was on blogger, would like to convert post title to meta keywords automatically on without plugins.

*E.g post title*: This is my title
*Post tags*: my title, mytitle

*keywords outcome*: 'This is my title, my title, mytitle'

> Any help would be appreciated I'm not a coder

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by setting code in header template like following,

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) : the_post();
$custom_fields = get_post_custom();
$custom_meta_description = $custom_fields['meta-description'];
$custom_meta_keywords = $custom_fields['meta-keywords'];
if ( !empty($custom_meta_description[0]) )
{
    echo "<meta http-equiv='description' content='" . $custom_meta_description[0] . "' />\\r\
";
}
if ( !empty($custom_meta_keywords[0]) )
{
    echo "<meta http-equiv='keywords' content='" . $custom_meta_keywords[0] . "' />\\r\
";
}
rewind_posts();
endif;
?>
```

After,

`<title><?php wp_title('&laquo;', true, 'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>`

Comment: Thanks but didn't work! 

took this from a keyword generator plugin if you can modify it to work without the plugin: <meta name="keywords" content="'.tp_parse($title).', '.tp_parse($name).$add.", ".$tp_mkg_options["tp_mkg_compulsary"].'" />